# Dynamic Row Height : UIcollectionView within UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

How can i achieve dynamic height for table view if my collection view height is dynamic ?
Basically need to have dynamic table view row height depending on collection view height.

Comment: How about setting top/bottom constraints from your table view to collection view?